# Compiling: Scons can't find libav

Tags: linker, compiler

The compiler errors I keep getting are:

```
error: ‘CODEC_ID_HUFFYUV’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     if (!codec) codec = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_HUFFYUV);
                                          ^
error:‘PIX_FMT_YUV422P’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     c->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV422P;
                  ^
error: ‘PIX_FMT_YUV420P’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     c->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
                  ^
error: ‘CODEC_ID_FFV1’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     if (c->codec_id == CODEC_ID_FFV1)
                    ^
error: ‘PIX_FMT_RGB24’
```

Which seem to be libav specific. I have ffmpeg installed, and have appropriate `pkgconfig` files at:

```
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libavutil.pc
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libavdevice.pc
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libavcodec.pc
```

I don't understand what's going on.

Edit - More info:

The errors stem from a single source file which has

```
#if HAVE_LAVC
# include <inttypes.h>
# if HAVE_LIBAVCODEC_AVCODEC_H
#  include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
# else
#  include <avcodec.h>
# endif
# if HAVE_LIBAVFORMAT_AVFORMAT_H
#  include <libavformat/avformat.h>
# else
#  include <avformat.h>
# endif
```

Comment: Whenever a build process complains about undeclared constants but **doesn't** complain about not finding header files, my first thought is an API mismatch i.e. the source code is expecting a different *version* of the headers/libs

Comment: That was along my reasoning also. I added some extra info that might help. How do I test to see which -D flags are being passed? Or which `<libblah>` libraries I have installed?

Comment: You should be able to get development version information using for example `pkg-config --modversion libavcodec`